# How to determine Mysql connection ID in Perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am trying to understand, do my modules share DBI connection to MySQL or no. I'd like to determine their connection ID. There may be better solutions (and i'd like to know them), but first question is still about knowing connection ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`CONNECTION_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) function, e.g.:

```
my ($id) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT CONNECTION_ID()');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too, as you're mentioning MySQL

```
my $threadId = $dbmyh->{ q{mysql_thread_id} };
```

From [DBD::mysql documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.024/lib/DBD/mysql.pm)